# Fetch Outlook mails in Sharepoint 2013 programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, outlook

Need to create a webpart that connects to Exchange server and retrieves certain emails of contacts in client contacts list of current logged in user.

Input Parameters for the webpart:
logged-in userid list of email addresses from the client contacts list.

so the webpart will query all the emails sent by or received by the loggedin userid specific to the people on the client contacts list.

Is this feasible?? Any help will be appreciated.